# Indian Passport stolen in France. Can Indian embassy in Austria issue a new passport?

Tags: france, passports, indian-citizens, austria, embassies

I am a student in Austria travelling around Europe. My Indian passport was stolen in France. I immediately reported the theft in the nearest police office and got myself a police report.

I have my exams in a couple of days and I can't  wait till the Indian embassy in Paris issues me a new passport. Can I travel ahead and produce the police report at the Indian embassy in Austria and obtain a duplicate passport without any issues? Or do I have to come back to Paris again for the new passport?

Comment: In general, an embassy/consulate is obliged to issue you a passport (or a temporary travel document) at least to get you back to your home country, regardless of where/how you lost it.

Comment: What is "an FIR"?

Comment: Oh I am sorry. FIR is a common terminology used in India for police reports.

Comment: FIR? Folice Information Report?

Comment: FIR is first information report http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Information_Report

Comment: Where are you now? I don't know about India specifically but generally speaking you should contact the nearest consulate and avoid crossing borders without proper documentation. Between France and Austria, it might be possible but still.

Comment: an excellent point.  as I comment from the doco. from the Indo-Austrianich web site, they actually assert that YOU SHOULD go to the embassy where you most definitively "live".  it's irrelevant where the problem happened.

Comment: Torrero - a worthwhile tip - here in Europe, we are quiet decadent.  Nobody cares much about "F-I-R" and similar concept.  To be totally honest, I wouldn't even bother mentioning to them any of the circumstances of the loss; I'd just say "I've lost it, give me a new one".

Answer (score 6):

The answer is: sure!  Go straight to your embassy in Vienna.

indeed, since you say you are "living in" .AT, that is where you should go.  (If you went to the Paris one, they might just tell you - oh, go to the Vienna one since you're living there.)

http://www.indianembassy.at/pages.php?id=19

"Issue of a duplicate passport, in case passport was lost, stolen or damaged (with 36 pages)

If an Indian national who is legally resident in Austria has either lost, damaged his/her Indian Passport or the passport has been stolen, he/she is required to approach the Embassy of India, Vienna to get a duplicate passport. A duplicate passport, just like a new passport, is valid for travel to all countries and is valid for ten years.

If an Indian national who is on a short visit to Austria and his/her Indian passport is lost, stolen or damaged within the period of validity of his/her Austria/Schengen visa, the individual is required to approach the Embassy immediately for a travel document.  Such individuals would be issued a short validity passport as they may not remain in Austria for 30 days, which is the time generally taken for preparing a full validity passport.

In case an individual on a short visit to Austria loses his/her passport and is unable to pay the requisite fees and wants to depart for India urgently, an Emergency Certificate is issued to him/her which is valid for return to India. Emergency Certificate issued to an Indian national by the Embassy does not validate travel to any other country and is meant for one way travel to India only.

A Short Validity Passport is issued for a period of six months only in the cases when the Embassy finds it necessary to issue  such Short Validity Passports.
"